# Is there a VSCode extension that adds a Quick Fix for adding the explicit type to a field for Typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I want to have a Quick Fix action (`cmd + .`) that adds the explicit type to a field, parameter, or function return (where it is otherwise inferred).

To turn

```js
const specificQuesiton = await Question.query().findById(1)
```

into

```js
const specificQuesiton: Question = await Question.query().findById(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found one!

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nick-lvov-dev.typescript-explicit-types

Here's an example of it in action:
[image]

I also found [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ebrithil30.vscode-ts-auto-return-type) which just does return type (the one above does everything).